# Understanding Linear Least Squares Problem Statement

Tags: linear-algebra, least-squares

My computer vision class is covering linear least squares problems with SVD.

In our notes, the problem statement is as follows:

min $\mid Ax - b\mid^2 = min(Ax - b)^T(Ax - b)$

= min $x^TA^TAx - 2b^TAx - b^Tb$

= min $x^TA^TAx - 2b^TAx$

However, I do not follow this logic.  Wouldn't the initial product expand as follows:

min $(Ax - b)^T(Ax - b)$ = min $(x^TA^T - b^T)(Ax - b)$

= min $x^TA^TAx - x^TA^Tb - b^TAx + b^Tb$

I am also struggling to understand why $b^Tb$ is removed from the equation.

Comment: Also, in your notes it should be $+b^T b$  instead of $-b^Tb$.

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering about that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, $b^T b$ is a known quantity, so it is sufficient to minimize (according to your thoughts)
$$x^T A^T A x - x^TA^Tb-b^T Ax.$$

But $x^TA^T b = (Ax)^T b = \langle Ax, b\rangle = b^T (Ax)$. Actually, $(Ax)^T b$ is the inner product of $Ax$ and $b$.

Thus, what we want to minimize is:
$$x^T A^T Ax - 2b^T Ax. $$

Comment: Thanks for the help!  Can I pick your brain with one more question?  How would I go about differentiating this final expression with respect to x?

Comment: I apologize if these are simple questions - this high level matrix algebra is relatively new to me.

Comment: I guess this [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus) will answer your question. Just scroll down.

Comment: Any way, you are welcome! Don't worry about the difficulty of the questions! We all keep studying and learning! : )